# display pdf in firefox using built in Preview in FireFox

Tags: php, firefox, header

From Google I have found that there are a lot if issues regarding Firefox's built in "Preview option" for PDF's. Workarounds found is to basically [disable the PDF viewer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-built-pdf-viewer-and-use-another-viewer) and use anther one. Unfortunately from a developers point of view, this is unacceptable as I will be unable to tell users to disable the previewer. I am asking the group am I doing something wrong, which is causing FireFox's Previewer to choke? basic few lines of code I am using to display the pdf is below. Am I missing something with my headers? Please note that the code works on IE and Chrome, as well as firefox if I change the viewer.

```
<?php 
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    echo $fileData;
?>
```

How the page renders with previewer enabled:
[image]

Comment: You are missing `;` after the echo. Is this the error you are looking for? What is not working and what is the actual behaviour?

Comment: nope, typo in question sorry

Comment: The php code does not render any errors.

Comment: Does it render PDF? Or blank screen? Do you have [error reporting enabled](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/)? Does `$fileData` contain correct binary PDF blob? Can you open the output with Adobe Reader (Save-as, or open straight URL)?

Comment: After doing some Googling, the PDF viewer likely has an issue with the actual code which makes up the PDF file. It could be having a problem with a font, color, decoration, image, or whatever so I am about 95% certain this won't be fixed with a PHP `header();`

Answer (score 2):

Frankly I can't figure out why we're wasting resources on re-inventing the wheel (ie, trying to replace Adobe Reader extensions); not to mention that so far I have not seen a single "replacement" -- including Chrome, etc. -- that offers the complete page zooom, format and viewing controls. Why don't we spend that energy on solving the print interface issues!! Or the fact that Firefox leaks like a sieve and crashes catastrophically when it mis-handles memory requests. Sure, Chrome leaks too but it does handle memory requests perfectly. For example, Firefox crashes pretty reliably once the Paged memory gets more than 2GB above my 3.5GB system RAM. But Chrome runs happily at 4-5GB Paged memory above that same system RAM and  I only restart it because the system slows below usefulness; it is only an old Pentium D after all. Which brings up another point. Years ago we used to make fun of Microsoft for their "bloatware" OS. Well, boys and girls, those same laughs now apply to all your "modern" software. Assembly might be harder but it sure was smaller and quicker.

Answer (score 0):

If the PDF renders Firefox spawning the external Adobe reader and other browsers, then you are doing everything right and the issue is with the PDF.js rendering.

What can you do about it?  Best solution is to fix the underlying issue in the PDF that is choking pdf.js -- could be font issue, or a text layer issue, or a few other things.  How do you find out what that issue is?  Try appending #disableWorker=true to your URL.

For example, open these URL in Firefox with the pdf.js enabled:

- http://www.vd.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/organisation/dinf/sm/fichiers_pdf/TP2020_sm_061010.pdf
- http://www.xfront.com/URLversusURN.pdf

Notice it gives you the warning or doesn't show up at all?  This is expected, bugs have been reported against [both](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=911761) [these](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=760746).  Now append the debug line:

- http://www.vd.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/organisation/dinf/sm/fichiers_pdf/TP2020_sm_061010.pdf#disableWorker=true
- http://www.xfront.com/URLversusURN.pdf#disableWorker=true

Either no more error or at least the contents show.  Not a magic bullet, and this might not work for you, but now you can follow the [debugging guide](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Debugging-pdf.js) to figure out what is going on and fix it in the PDF itself.

Answer (score 0):

append #disableFontFace=true to the URL

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a defect in PDF.js (one of hundreds). Since some time Firefox comes with a PDF reader implemented in javascript, which frankly should never have been put into production in the state that it is now.

Feel free to [file a new issue for PDF.js, attaching your PDF file](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues).