# Chrome or Firefox: Javascript to save as pdf

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Is there any way that I can force google chrome/Firefox to download as `PDF`, I mean if any of them provide any API or anything to achieve this using javascript?

Comment: Are you asking for saving the html/webpage to pdf ?

Comment: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20552715/2908724), I describe a little about `PDF.js`, which may be useful in some circumstances.